# pandas.Timedelta conversion to seconds in float is too slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named `_df`, whose `len` is 3.7M, having two `pandas.Timestamp` columns `timestamp` and `lead_timestamp`. I want to add a new column `diff_timestamp` as differences of the two columns in seconds.

The following snippet

```
_df["diff_timestamp"] = _df.timestamp - _df.lead_timestamp
```

cost less than 0.1 second.

But when I modify it as following:

```
_df["diff_timestamp"] = (_df.timestamp - _df.lead_timestamp).map(lambda x: x.seconds)
```

It takes more than 25 seconds, about 300 times longer.

Is there any more efficient way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
_df["diff_timestamp"] = (_df.timestamp - _df.lead_timestamp).dt.total_seconds()
```

Another idea:

```
_df["diff_timestamp"] = (_df.timestamp - _df.lead_timestamp) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

Comment: Both idea worked perfectly. In my environment, the first one runs in 43ms and the latter 98ms.